# Avoid repetition in code in wcf and ef

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I have 10 code blocks just similar to each other.

Two of them are as below:

```
[OperationContract]
public IEnumerable<HaemogramReport> GetHaemogramReports(int patientId)
{
    using (Lab_Lite_Entities db = new Lab_Lite_Entities())
    {
        var result = db.HaemogramReports.Where(h => h.Patients.Any(p => p.PatientID == patientId)).ToList();
        result.ForEach(h => ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Detach(h));
        return result;
    }
}

[OperationContract]
public IEnumerable<UrineAnalysis> GetUrineAnalysises(int patientId)
{
    using (Lab_Lite_Entities db = new Lab_Lite_Entities())
    {
        var result = db.UrineAnalysises.Where(u => u.Patients.Any(p => p.PatientID == patientId)).ToList();
        result.ForEach(u => ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Detach(u));
        return result;
    }
}
```

First method contains `db.HaemogramReports` and Second method contains `db.UrineAnalysises`. Except that every thing is similar. This is the similar behavior for all ten methods. So, how can I re-format my code to avoid repetition?

Comment: First of all, why do you think you need to detach the entities? Won't that happen when `Lab_Lite_Entities` is disposed of at the end of the `using` block? And why covert to `List<T>` in any case?

Comment: I am following a video tutorial and so I have detached it as he uses it. and thank you for your suggestion. I will delete that code. I dont understand what do you mean by Why `Convert to List<T>?`

Comment: Take a look at the [repository pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2013/08/23/using-repository-pattern-in-entity-framework.aspx).

Comment: Do I read your code correctly? `UrineAnalysise` has many `Patients`? and `HaemogramReport` also has many `Patients`? Is that correct domain structure? Should it not be other way round? Patient has many reports and analyses?

Comment: @trailmax it is many-to-many relationship between reports and patients.

Comment: So a single report can be assigned to many different patients? sounds wrong to my, but this is your call. I'm just curious. And by the way, there is no _simple_ way to improve your code.

Comment: @trailmax Thank you for your suggestion. You have directed me to the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer.

For 10 cases, it's probably not worth the effort.

But you could do something where you define an interface for "things that have a list of patients". Create another class part for your entities which have a Patients list to force them to implement the interface. Then you could write a generic method that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` where T is defined to implement the interface. That method could then execute the predicate on the patients list.

Comment: Sorry, but I am a newbie and I don't understand what you want to explain. Can you say it in some simple terms?

Comment: Yeah. There's no simple way to solve the problem. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I want to follow your answer but can you explain that in some simple terms like giving me an example?

Comment: An example wouldn't help you. I really mean that you shouldn't worry about it for such a small amount of duplication.